# Как правильнее делать загрузку файлов через REST API - POST или PUT?

Tags: файлы, api, post, rest, put

Как вы считаете, каким из двух методов правильнее загружать файлы в рамках концепции REST API: POST или PUT? Интересуют различные мнения и ссылки на правила.

Comment: Ну норм. А что может быть не так? Не через  DELETE же))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так через POST или PUT правильно?

Comment: .............Да

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вопрос в том какой метод выбрать из двух: POST или PUT? :-) я считаю, что POST, так как на сервере все же создается файл, а если что-то создается, то PUT не может быть. Возникла дискуссия, решили спросить у хорошо знающих принципы REST

Comment: Что-то никто не горит желанием написать подробный ответ. Очевидно, проще вам будет погуглить про разницу PUT и POST. Во многих статьях это обясняется. Про идемпотентность и прочее. А также немаловажно то, что многие системы не умеют работать ни с чем кроме POST и GET.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не понимаю зачем так ёрничать. Да, вопрос простой .. ну так и дайте простой ответ или пройдите мимо )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходя из общих соображений:

- если это новый файл, то POST
- если обновляете существующий, то PUT.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отсюда новый вопрос: что лучше использовать для обновления - PUT или PATCH? :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вы можете задать новый вопрос ;-)

Comment: А если это форма, не знаю, с комментарием под постом и там есть поле для фото.  Текст обновляют а фото прикладывают (то есть создают), то что использовать?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Казалось бы ответ в самой формулировке - "Текст *обновляют* а фото *прикладывают*". Это составное действие. Тут уже наверное от архитектуры зависит - как обрабатывать подобные действия. Такой же вопрос впрочем будет, например при "пост редактируют, а фото удаляют".